# Can Initial Current on replacement battery be higher?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I want to replace the battery below. As shown below, the current battery says the `Initial Current` is `Less than 2.10A`. The new battery is the same except that `Initial Current` is `Less than 3.6A`.

Is the new battery compatible? What is the benefit of having 3.6A over 2.1A?

[image]

Comment: The batteries are different. It depends on the circuit where the battery is if the new is compatible or not. Simply because the new battery allows to be charged faster by using higher current than the original, it is still unknown at what voltage and current the system will charge it.

Comment: The new battery has same voltage and current (6V7AHh/20Hr) like this current one. The only difference in the Initial Current. The battery (actual 2 identical batteries) is used in a drivable toy car.

Comment: That's not current. Ah is capacity.

Answer (score 2):

The batteries are identical except the new battery could be charged with higher current. The charger applies whatever current it wants to charge it so at least the new battery is not worse handling it.

Comment: So, if the new battery has same `6V7AHh/20Hr` values but different max carger current (Initial Current), can I use that battery instead of the old one?

Comment: @theateist I thought I already said yes.

Comment: I just need to make sure that the charger doesn't allow to draw more than 3.6A otherwise the battery might draw more current than 3.6A during the charging and be damaged?

Comment: Yes, but if the original battery was only rated to 2.1A and the new is rated to 3.6A, the new battery is better, and the charger should have been limited to 2.1A anyway because the product was shipped with a 2.1A battery.

Comment: Why to limit it to 2.1A anyway if the new battery supports up to 3.6A? Doesn't it just affect how fast it will charge the battery? If I allow it to draw it's max of 3.6A won't it take less time to charge the battery than if I limit it to 2.1A?

Comment: Yes but you can't change the charger you already have. Even if the batteries could charge at 100A in a few minutes, you still have the old charger, programmed to charge at whatever current it happens to provide. Which hopefully is 2.1A max in case of the old battery, or max 3.6A in case of the new battery. The charger won't know your new battery could be charged at higher current.

Answer (score 1):

The actual initial current is not higher. The battery supplies current on demand and must accept the current delivered by the charger.

Since the initial current on charge must be less than 2.1 amps on the original, then the replacement will have no problem with excess current supplied by the charge because 2.1A<3.6A.

The replacement will work.